# Add bootstrap modal in admin theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using drupal 7 and I've bootstrap 3 theme in main theme and Seven is the admin theme.

I created new user profile and I wanted these users can edit different things in admin panel so I enabled admin theme for them, but there is a problem with bootstrap modals.

In user edit pages there is "Terms of Use" in modal dialog. That works as well, but when this target user who has admin theme access that dialog not open.

So what I need to do so I get this modal works in seven profile edit page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boostrap library module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_library) to load it on any pages. You can also configure it to load in only on css or js.